# "selection sort" using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

How to get the position of smallest element in an array and swap with that value with neighbor value for "selection sort" using javascript?

```js
var list = [];
Math.max.apply(Math, list); //maximum
Math.min.apply(Math, list); //minimum 


function getInput() {
  var str_one = document.getElementById("one").value;
  var str_two = document.getElementById("two").value;
  var str_three = document.getElementById("three").value;
  var str_four = document.getElementById("four").value;
  var str_five = document.getElementById("five").value;
  var str_six = document.getElementById("six").value;
  list.push(str_one, str_two, str_three, str_four, str_five, str_six);
  $('#qstnDiv').html(list + ',');
}

function output() {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <form onsubmit="store(this); return false">
    1:<input type="text" id="one" /><br /> 2:
    <input type="text" id="two" /><br /> 3:
    <input type="text" id="three" /><br /> 4:
    <input type="text" id="four" /><br /> 5:
    <input type="text" id="five" /><br /> 6:
    <input type="text" id="six" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="getInput(); output();" />
  </form><br />
  <p id="in">Input</p><br />
  <div id="qstnDiv"></div><br />
  <p id="out">Output</p><br />
  <div id="anwrDiv"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I want sort the numbers form the text box using selection sort so please help me

Comment: Why does it need to be selection sort? Javascript already provides a simple enough `.sort()` function

Comment: actually i wanna do the sort function step by step that's why... please help me to find the solution.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Comment: could you please send me the Javascript code for selection sort?

Comment: bhb linked a pseudo code for selection sort, now rewrite it in JS should not be very difficult.

Comment: @BeNdErR pls hlp me...

Answer (score 1):

there is a specific function for this.

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
```

this is ascending. if you change the order of "a" and "b" it become discending.
if you need to access into an object you have to write

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b){return b.propertyName-a.propertyName});
```

Answer (score 0):

Very explicit selection sort!

```
function selectionSort(arr){
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        let indexOfMin = i // set index of min to the 
        let j = i // set the index to run the while loop for calculating min
        let min = arr[i] // set the initial value of minimum

        // find the minimum from i to end of array
        while (j < arr.length){
            if (arr[j] < min){
                min = arr[j]
                indexOfMin = j
            }
            j++
        }

        if (indexOfMin !== i){ // only swap if the index of minimum and curr item is different
            let tmp = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[indexOfMin]
            arr[indexOfMin] = tmp
            console.log(arr)
        }
    }
    return arr
}

sortedList = selectionSort([5,3,4,1,-3,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Selection sort:** swapping doesn't occur like in bubble sort, rather it happens once per iteration setting the min value in array.

```
const selectionSort = (arr) => {
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
       let lowest = i;
        for(let j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++) {
            if(arr[lowest] > arr[j]) {
                lowest = j;
            }
        }
        if(i != lowest) {
           // SWAP!!
           [arr[lowest], arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[lowest]]; 
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(selectionSort([8,1,2,3,4,5,6]));
```